# Downloading large files from a Google Cloud bucket in a BullMQ worker leads to stalls

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, message-queue, bull, bullmq

I've created a job scheduler/runner using BullMQ. I have a worker that, when handling a job, downloads a given file from a Google Cloud Bucket and then analyzes it.

However, whenever the file to download is very large (>10GB), it can take several minutes to download and leads to the error: "job stalled more than allowable limit" error.

```
const GCS = new Storage();
await GCS.bucket(bucket).file(file).download({
    destination
});
```

These workers are setup as "sandboxed workers" and therefore shouldn't be stalling out according to the [docs](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/jobs/stalled):

> In order to avoid stalled jobs, make sure that your worker does not
> keep Node.js event loop too busy, the default max stalled check
> duration is 30 seconds, so as long as you do not perform CPU
> operations exceeding that value you should not get stalled jobs.
> Another way to reduce the chance for stalled jobs is using so called
> "sandboxed" processors. In this case, the workers will spawn new
> separate Node.js processes, running separately from the main process.

Based on the explanation of [Sandboxed Processors](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/workers/sandboxed-processors), it seems like the source of the stalling error is due to overwhelming the CPU...but is downloading a large file from a GCS bucket even a CPU intensive operation?

> Since these workers run the processor in a different process, they
> will not result in stalled jobs as easily as standard workers,
> although it is not completely impossible if the CPUs in the system are
> so overload that there is no practical time for the worker to perform
> its bookkeeping to avoid stalling.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to check this [post](https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq/discussions/633) if this will address your concern?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that for very large file downloads, the job runs for too long and registers as stalled (see https://docs.bullmq.io/bull/important-notes for more info).

The fix was increasing the 'lock duration' from the default 30 seconds to 5 minutes.

```
const worker = new Worker('my-queue', null, { lockDuration: 60000 });
```